# How to mock next/router for unit testing with vitest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vitest

When trying to write simple tests for out Next.js app that uses `useRouter()` hook, `vitest` starts throwing errors.

Looking for ways to mock next/router for unit testing with vitest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research and trial and error, I figured out the way to mock `next/router`.

You need to create a setup file for your test setup and configure `vitest` to use that.

```
// vitest.config.js/ts
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: ["vitestSetup.ts"],
  },
});
```

Now create `vitestSetup.ts` in the root directory with the following content.

```
// vitestSetup.ts
import { beforeAll, vi } from "vitest";
beforeAll(() => {
  vi.mock("next/router", () => require("next-router-mock"));
}
```

Congratulations! You have successfully mocked `next/router`.